# Error when load more data with event scroll of listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have problem with scroll of listview. I have a class like:

```
private int itemsPerPage = 6;
private int count = 0;
private boolean loadingMore = false;
private ArrayList<Item> item;
private ListItemAdapter adapter;
View footerView;
private JSONArray array;
private String json;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    lvListItem = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvListItem);
    item = new ArrayList<Item>();
    footerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.list_footer, null, false);

    json = new JSONParse()
                    .getData("....");
    array = new JSONArray(json);

    load();
    adapter = new ListItemAdapter(this, 0, item);
    lvListItem.addFooterView(footerView);
    lvListItem.setAdapter(adapter);

    lvListItem.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

            // is the bottom item visible & not loading more already ? Load
            // more !
            if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(null, loadData);
                thread.start();
            }
        }
    });
    }

public void load(){
for (int i = 0; i < itemsPerPage; i++) {
    if (count == array.length()) {
        lvListItem.removeFooterView(footerView);
        break;
    }
    /*****Code to load data*******/
}
}


private Runnable loadData = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        loadingMore = true;


        item = new ArrayList<Item>();


        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        load();


        runOnUiThread(returnRes);

    }
};


private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {


        if (item != null && item.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++)
                adapter.add(item.get(i));
        }


        if (count == array.length())
            lvListItem.removeFooterView(footerView);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Done loading more.
        loadingMore = false;
    }
};
```

if i just using **load()**, it run and listview show data ok. But when I scrolling listview, it throw error:

> ```
>  D/AndroidRuntime(1635): Shutting down VM
>   W/dalvikvm(1635): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(1635): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>    E/AndroidRuntime(1635): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 6
>    E/AndroidRuntime(1635):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(1635):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
> ```

I need a help

Comment: Is that the entire stacktrace?

Comment: Do you manipulate `item` in load()?

Comment: Yes, i add value to item in load()

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your array has only 6 elements and you are trying to access the element  with index 6 which is effectively the  7th element so

Change

```
itemsPerPage = 5;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not threadsafe at all. You are accessing shared data from multiple threads without any kind of locking. It is possible that your `item` array is being reinitialized in your worker thread while it is being read from in your `resultRes` runnable (running on the main thread), which would result in seemingly impossible out of bounds exceptions.

Create an object to use as your mutex:

```
private final Object monitor = new Object(); // an ivar in your Activity
```

Then when accessing shared data (like `item` and `loadingMore`), create a critical section, for example:

```
synchronized(monitor) {
    item = new ArrayList<Item>();
}

synchronized(monitor) {
    if (item != null && item.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++)
            adapter.add(item.get(i));
    }
}

synchronized(monitor) {
    if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(null, loadData);
        thread.start(); // will exit critical section before new thread execution begins
    }
}
```

And so on. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to figure out where the rest of the locking should be done.

Comment: When i get data from array, it worked but when i get data from webservice, it's not work